# Is there a way to enable / disable 3rd party COM Add-ins for MS Word 2007 not through GUI?

Tags: microsoft-office, windows

I need somehow enable / disable 3rd party COM Add-ins in MS Word 2007 individually without accessing Word GUI. Is it possible to somehow control them trough registry or via some script / CLI options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, those addins can be enabled/disabled from the registry.

More info in this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106.aspx

Comment: Could you please mark this answer as the correct one? Thank you :-)